# Simple download counter sometimes resets to 0

Tags: php

I have a simple download counter thats sees some fairly heavy use, but I notice every now and the it will reset to 0, I assume due to some sort of file locking issue. Given the code I am using now, are there any precautions I can be taking to avoid this?

```
$DLFile = $_GET['Link'];
$DLFilePathParts = pathinfo($DLFile);
$CounterFile = $DLFilePathParts['dirname']."/".$DLFilePathParts['basename'].".cnt";

$fh = fopen($CounterFile, 'r+');
$count = (int)fgets($fh);
fclose($fh);
$fh = fopen($CounterFile, 'w+');
fwrite($fh, ++$count);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Yes, [`flock`](http://php.net/flock) with an atomic [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) FILE_EX.

Comment: @mario How do I write blocking code to wait until unlock if lock fails? just wrap it in a `while` loop? Or does the flock function block already?

Comment: @mario: `file_put_contents` is not atomic.

Comment: @Wobbles have you checked the `flock` documentation page?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, the doc claims it is blocking, but in the example i see it wrapped in an if/else, is that to handle timeouts?

Comment: @Wobbles: there are no timeouts - it either waits until it acquires the lock or fails immediately if non-blocking option is used.

Comment: @zerkms Don't understand how it can be blocking then if it fails on unsuccessful lock.

Comment: @Wobbles: "Don't understand how it can be blocking then if it fails on unsuccessful lock" --- for blocking option it fails if it physically could not obtain the lock, if say your operating system does not provide such facility.

Comment: @zerkms ahh gotcha, the documentation was a lil spotty on that, ill give it a shot, thanks